# How can I Keep a moving object centered on Leafllet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have positioned this satellite on a leaflet map, it is changing locations every 5 seconds. I want to keep the moving object centered on the map so it does not get lost and disappear from sight. here is HTML and JS code:

JS

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0], 2);

function moveISS () {
    $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json?callback=?', function(data) {
        var lat = data['iss_position']['latitude'];
        var lon = data['iss_position']['longitude'];
        iss.setLatLng([lat, lon]);
        isscirc.setLatLng([lat, lon]);
        map.panTo([lat, lon], animate=true);
    });
    setTimeout(moveISS, 5000); 
}



var styled = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
    type: 'roadmap',
    styles: [
        {elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]},
        {featureType: 'water', stylers: [{color: '#444444'}]}
    ]
}).addTo(map);
var roads = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
    type: 'terrain' // valid values are 'roadmap', 'satellite', 'terrain' and 'hybrid'
}).addTo(map);
L.terminator().addTo(map);

//L.terminator().addTo(map);//
//http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/favicon.ico//
//https://www.n2yo.com/inc/saticon.php?t=0&amp;s=25544
//L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}', {foo: 'bar'}).addTo(map);//




var ISSIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'file:///C:/Users/rez/Downloads/noun_24414.svg',
    iconSize: [50, 30],
    iconAnchor: [25, 15],
    popupAnchor: [50, 25],
    shadowUrl: 'file:///C:/Users/rez/Downloads/noun_24414.svg',
    shadowSize: [30, 20],
    shadowAnchor: [15, 8]
});

var iss = L.marker([0, 0], {icon: ISSIcon}).addTo(map);
moveISS();
```

```html
<p id="isstime">WHERE IS ISS?</p>
<br>
<div id="map"> </div>
<script src="iss.js"> </script>
<br>
```

Comment: The code generates errors because there are missing dependencies. Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that only produces the error your question is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed some parts of your code and modified the `moveISS` function a little:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 4);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

function moveISS() {
  $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json?callback=?', function(data) {
    var lat = data['iss_position']['latitude'];
    var lon = data['iss_position']['longitude'];
    iss.setLatLng([lat, lon]);
    map.panTo([lat, lon], {animate: true});
  });
  setTimeout(moveISS, 5000);
}

var iss = L.marker([0, 0]).addTo(map);
moveISS();
```

The moving marker is kept centered on the map.

Check it out [in this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/caliqap/4/edit?js,output).

Comment: Thank You ! Just removing 
        isscirc.setLatLng([lat, lon]);
did the job. The moving object is now focused. appreciate your help.

Comment: Please check a live version of the website here :
www.isslivecam.com

Comment:  awesome! Thanks for sharing.